# What should I do to change this array from random to appearing in sequence on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

Here is the code...
I'm new to this. Thanks in advance for any advice!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
var url = "http://localhost:8888/wordpress_hattie/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/",
    imgArray = [url+"paper_shape3.svg",
               url+"mustard_shape2.svg",
               url+"alt_shape.svg"],
    randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * imgArray.length)),
    baseUrl = "url('" + imgArray[randomNumber] + "')";
$(".par_layer").css('background-image', baseUrl);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: you want to display the first element in the array or all of them?

Comment: i want to display a different image from the array on each refresh of the page... i think it is to do with changing the 'randomNumber' line to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the index of the previously used image in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and increment the index each time the script runs.

```
var basePath = 'http://localhost:8888/wordpress_hattie/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/';
var fileNames = ['paper_shape3.svg', 'mustard_shape2.svg', 'alt_shape.svg'];
var index = 0;

// Get last index from localStorage if present and increment it by 1.
if (localStorage.getItem('index') !== null) {
  index = Number(localStorage.getItem('index')) + 1;
}

// Reset index to 0 if it exceeds the bounds of fileNames.
if (index >= fileNames.length) {
  index = 0;
}

// Store index in localStorage for later use.
localStorage.setItem('index', index);

$('.par_layer').css('background-image', 'url(' + basePath + fileNames[index] + ')');
```

Comment: thanks. I am just trying to implement this, it is not working at present... but i will keep trying to make it work

Comment: the issue currently is that it is showing 'paper_shape3.svg' and not changing on refresh...

Comment: What does `Number(localStorage.getItem('index'))` return when you paste it in your console?

Comment: the console returns 0

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant `localStorage.getItem('index')`, without the type casting. Since `Number(null)` is also `0`.

Comment: Strange. This would mean that the value gets stored but never incremented and stored for some reason.

Comment: could it be to do with the site being localhost not actually live?

Comment: I haven't actually tested my code because Stack Overflow doesn't allow localstorage in their code embeds. I'll set it up locally and see if there is a bug.

Comment: Looks like I somehow had special characters in there that don't show up int the font used to display code on Stack Overflow. If you copy paste it again it should work.

Comment: No problem. If my answer helped you please mark it so.

Answer (score 1):

I would use cookies:

```
var r, m, i;
r = /(?:^|;)\s*i=([^;]+)/;
m = document.cookie.match(r);
i = m ? parseInt(m[1], 10) : 0;
console.log(i); // prints "0" then "1" then "2" then "0"...
document.cookie = "i=" + (++i % 3);
```

Alright dear poster, let's save your precious time:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
var url = "http://localhost:8888/wordpress_hattie/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/",
    imgArray = [url+"paper_shape3.svg", url+"mustard_shape2.svg", url+"alt_shape.svg"],
    r = /(?:^|;)\s*i=([^;]+)/,
    m = document.cookie.match(r),
    i = m ? parseInt(m[1], 10) : 0,
    baseUrl = "url('" + imgArray[i] + "')";
$(".par_layer").css('background-image', baseUrl);
document.cookie = "i=" + (++i % imgArray.length);
})();
</script>
```

Side note: Won't work if cookies are disabled.

Pedantic note: Same for `localStorage`.